# How can I define the function body in a .h file?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, header-files

Sometimes I define bodies of small global functions in .h files (static inline). It works.

Now I have larger global function. I need to to define it in .h file. I do not want it to be static inline. I tried the following trick with "dummy template":

```
template <typename Tunused> int myfunction(...) {
    ...
}
```

to achieve this -- to define global function in .h file.

Compiler complains "cannot deduce template argument for 'unused'".

Do you guys understand what I an trying to do ? How can I trick the compiler ? I think I need to unsert some dummy usage of template arg into the function so that compiler can deduce it.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Any time you find yourself asking "how can I trick the compiler", warning bells should go off. There's a 99.9% chance that whatever you're trying to do is wrong. In this case, it's not clear why you think you *need* the function body to go in the header file. There's a *reason* that a function in a header file becomes an inline function. You're not going to trick the compiler; it will win every time because it's the one that does the work. Find a way to work within the language's parameters.

Comment: Andrei: The `inline` keyword does not do what you think (i.e. it does not actually inline functions).

Comment: What's the motivation here? It might help if you explained why you didn't just put it in a .cpp file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I don't recommend putting large non-template function's definition
in .h file unless there is definite reason that you can't put the definition
in .cpp file.
If you have to put the definition in .h, the following code might help:

```
// .h
template< int Unused > int myfunction_() {
  // definition
}

namespace { int (&myfunction)() = myfunction_<0>; }

// .cpp
int main() { myfunction(); }
```

If you could show the reason that you have to put the definition in .h,
better suggestions may be posted.

**Edit:**
Rewrote the code in the light of Bo Persson's pointing out.

Comment: Hmm cool I did not know that I can initialize global vars if I put them into namespace. I definitely have uses use for this.

Comment: Are you sure this works? If I were to include this .h in several .cpp files, I would expect multiple definition problems for myfunction_<0>.

Comment: @BoPersson @Andrei: Thank you for pointing out! I think Bo Persson is right. I neglected sufficient confirmation. I'm sorry for posting incomplete and incorrect answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just put its prototype in the .h file, and its implementation in a single .c file:

In .h file:

```
int myFunc( int x );
```

In .c file:

```
int myFunc( int x )
{
    return x + 4;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I agree. "Abandon that silly idea of declaring a function in the header file and put it in a .cpp file, instead."

Comment: Bogatyr and Cody. First, this is c++ question not C. In C, clearly, there would be no such option.In C++, there are whole libraries that keep ALL code in .h files. Class code, just no problem, it goes into .h file without problem. Global function are more subtle, hence my question.

Comment: What's subtle about it?  Put a prototype in the .h file and the function in the .cpp file (not .c, fine).   Works great.

Comment: @Andrei: I didn't miss the question being about C++. You're missing the part about those libraries defining *templates* in header files. You're explicitly *not* creating a template, but yet you want to trick the compiler into thinking that you are. Even if you win, you still lose. There's no reason to put function definitions in a header file, and plenty of good reasons *not* to. For starters, linker errors.

Comment: The question is for tough template experts like Ise, below.  C++ has more options for forcing linker to behave than C, and templates is one of them.  Templates are not the "I can do C++ without knowing templates" thing.  Templates are C++'s strengh to be learned and used.  I learned couple of template triks from Ise, below, which was my goal.  The question was *not* wrong question. It has solution(s), which lie in the direction of templates and, it turns out, namespaces.

Comment: @Andrei: The answer provided by Ise says *exactly* the same thing I've been saying from the beginning: you should place your code (definitions) in .cpp files, instead of .h files. Beyond that, your question asks about creating "dummy templates" to *trick* the compiler. Ise's answer assumes that you're creating an *actual* template. Those are two *very* different things, the distinction between which you seem to have forgotten. I'm glad you learned something, but you learned something about *templates*, not about dummy templates.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use "static" on functions merely so you can define them in a header, use "inline" for that.

And once you use "inline", you don't need any template "tricks", just define the function:

```
inline int myfunction(...) {/*...*/}
```

When you want to move the definition out of the header, remove the inline and define the function in a .cpp file.

Comment: Large function, I don't it to be inlined.

Comment: Andrei: Just because you mark it inline doesn't mean the compiler will actually inline the call, but it does mean you can define the function in every translation unit which is what happens when it's defined in a header.

Comment: Andrei: What makes you think that?  You can always not define the function in your header.

Comment: @Andrei: But if you don't want it to be inline, put the function declaration in h-file and the function definition in cpp-file.

Comment: @Andrei: you use the inline keyword for functions that are defined in header files. That way the compiler knows not to produce duplicates, even if the file is included several times. Whether the function is inlined or not is still up to the compiler. Really! If it agrees with you that your large function is too large to inline, it will not inline it. Trust your compiler!

Comment: @Bo Persson: It's more complicated than that, as it's the linker that knows to discard duplicates (rather than the compiler).  Thinking in terms of compiler and linker is slightly more complicated for beginners, but I think the bit of extra work is paid back in spades.

Comment: Bo: if "static" is missing, and compiler is not inlining, you get duplucation errors from linker.  That'swhy we need to write "static inline" not "inline".

Comment: @Andrei: If you use `inline static` the code will be duplicated in each translation unit, but if you only use `inline` there will only be one, as `inline` implies external linkage.

Comment: @Andrei: The whole point of "inline" is that you *don't* get duplication errors from the linker.  Don't use "static" for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to do this and are paranoid about inlining. You could do the following:

```
#ifdef DEFINE_MY_FUNCTION
int myfunction(...) {
    ...
}
#else
// just declare it
int myfunction(...);
#endif
```

Then just `#define DEFINE_MY_FUNCTION` before *one* of your `#include "myheader.h"` lines (in a cpp file).

However, there are many reasons to go the conventional route, as others have advised, not least the fact that any implementation tweaks will require recompilation of any file that uses `myfunction()`.

Comment: Sooo, where is the function defined if `DEFINE_MY_FUNCTION` is *not* defined?

Comment: While this "works" according to the technical requirements, never do this in your code.

Comment: @Cody. Indeed, you'll get a link error. I never said this was a *good* solution. (I actually up-voted Bogatyr's answer).

Comment: Call me traditional, but when I get a linker error, I would argue that my code "doesn't work". Similarly, I'm not sure how the "solution" proposed here (good or not) works. I thought maybe I was missing something obvious.

Comment: @Cody: Yes, I think you are missing something. When you define the symbol in a cpp file before including the header, the definition of the function is compiled. This is the definition that the linker finds for all of the other occurrences (where only the declaration is compiled.)